# how to get loop to solve common divisor method

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, while-loop

how do I get this loop to print all the divisors with two user inputted numbers including 1 but just print 1 and relatively prime when the two numbers have no common divisors.

```
 System.out.println("Common divisors of " + a + " and " + b + ":");
        for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++)
            if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0) {
               if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                if (i == 1)
                    System.out.println("Relatively Prime");


            }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter two positive integers:");
        int input1 = scan.nextInt();
        int input2 = scan.nextInt();
        printCommonDivisors(input1, input2);
    }
}
```

Right now it says relatively prime after 1 even if the numbers have common divisors.

I am just trying to get it to say relatively prime when the two numbers only common divisor is 1 but also not print relatively prime after 1 when the numbers do have more common divisors. this the output right now.
Please enter two positive integers:
10
20
Common divisors of 10 and 20:
1
Relatively Prime
2
5
10

Comment: So... How about `if (i > 1)` instead? Also the phrase "relatively prime" does not appear in the code you posted, so you might want to double check in case you left out something relevant, which right now it looks to be the case

Comment: Please put that in the question (you can edit it), not as a comment. And again, why are you doing `if (i>=1)`?

Comment: fixed it I don't know how else to make it say relatively prime when i = 1.

Comment: `if (i == 1)`  should be the `else` branch of an `if/else` where the `if` branch is `if (i > 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `boolean` value to store whether you have found a greater-than-one divisor inside the loop. Instead of

```
if (i == 1)
  System.out.println("Relatively Prime");
```

Check the boolean value after the loop and print "Relatively Prime" if a divisor was not found.

You have the line `if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0) {` twice, you only need to have one of it, make sure to remove the closing brace for it as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print "relatively prime" only if there were no other divisors, you should check for other divisors first (for instance by starting with the large numbers and working your way down, rather than starting with small numbers and working your way up) and if you find one, somehow record this fact so you later know not print "relatively prime".

In code:

```
boolean divisorFound = false;
for (int i = b; i > 1; i--) {
  if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0) {
    System.out.println(i);
    divisorFound = true;
  }
}
System.out.println(1);
if (!divisorFound) {
  System.out.println("relatively prime");
}
```

Of course, there are more efficient algorithms. For instance, one could use [euklid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to efficiently determine the greatest common divisor, then find its prime factors, and use that to efficiently iterate all divisors.

> this works good but the output code is in descending order I need it ascending sadly

Actually, since we take the 1 out of the loop, the order of the loop doesn't matter anymore :-)

```
System.out.println(1);
boolean divisorFound = false;
for (int i = 2; i <= b; i++) {
  if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0) {
    System.out.println(i);
    divisorFound = true;
  }
}
if (!divisorFound) {
  System.out.println("relatively prime");
}
```

Comment: this works good but the output code is in descending order I need it ascending sadly